# Fill in objects in another object

Tags: mesh, faces

I need to fill a box up with objects. See picture. I'm totally new to Blender and haven't found any answer to this question online. Its mostly how to fill (cover with a face) or animations with rigid body, so if someone could point me in a direction it would be great! Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: array modifier could help but with clean and ordered fill, no randomness.

Comment: Could particles be used?

Comment: @Bithur thanks for the comment, I'll read about it.

Comment: @RayMairlot have read that post.. I just thought there was another option other than ridig body. But I will try with that.

Comment: Yes particles can be used. just make an emitter above the box dump into it. I used a very similar effect [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NrCby.png). Of course, that wasn't *entirely* full, but it could've been.